# Designer Workflow trimming the current item URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I had this SharePoint 2010 designer workflow, which was working correctly till few days back. The workflow was sending URL to current path in a email to users. Suddenly it sent mail which trimmed the hostname from URL when user received the mail.

Hence users are getting page not found error on clicking on the link. Below is a screenshot of the workflow.

[image]

So now when user received mail the link was like

> /sites/sitename/lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

Instead of:

> `http://hostname.company.com/sites/sitename/lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`

Any thoughts why it suddenly trimmed the initial part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I get the same result on my end. As a workaround, you could use [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%] in the workflow to get current item URL.[image]

Comment: I wonder, how it was working before. User has shared last month mail with me where link is correct in email body. In this month only the link is getting trimmed.

Comment: Hi Michael, some more information on this, if we forward that same workflow mail to other user the link works. But the actual mail in my mailbox which i received from workflow, the link does not work. We have ATP security enabled for safe links. Do you think this is causing the issue?